# Show value of all totals in controller action

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, sales, totals, sales-quote

I need to log the values of all totals from a controller action.
If the controller action is called, then i need a list rendered which shows the totals:

If you are not familiar with totals then look at the screenshot of the cart below:

[image: Totals]

All items in the list are totals.

How can I render a specific total after my controller action is called?
For example I need my controller action `getGesamtsummeAction()` to get the value of `GESAMTSUMME` (grand_total) ,`RAL ZWISCHENSUMME` (ral_zwischensumme) and all the others and log or show them.

I need help to write the code for the controller action, everything else is already done.

```
public function getGesamtsummeAction()
{
    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

    ...???

}
```

---

Install script:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup $installer
 */

Mage::Log("wr_epo_sales_setup: ral_zwischensumme überall hinzugefügt", 7, "setup.log");

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


    $installer->addAttribute('quote_item', 'ral_zwischensumme',
        array(
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'RAL Zwischensumme'
        )
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('order_item', 'ral_zwischensumme',
        array(
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'RAL Zwischensumme'
        )
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('invoice', 'ral_zwischensumme',
        array(
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'RAL Zwischensumme'
        )
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('creditmemo', 'ral_zwischensumme',
        array(
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'RAL Zwischensumme'
        )
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

Model:

```
<?php

class WR_EPO_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Ral_Zwischensumme extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Berechnen des gesamten Versandaufpreises
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return Webkochshop_Versandaufpreis_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping_Surcharge
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $total = Mage::helper("wr_epo")->getRalZwischensumme($address);
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();

        /*
         * In dem Address Model ablegen zur späteren Referenz in fetch()
         */
        $address->setRalZwischensumme($total);

        if ($total > 0) {
            $quote->setRalZwischensumme($total);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Den Versandaufpreis in die Basiswährung des Shops umrechnen
     *
     * @param float $amount
     * @return float $amount konvertiert in die Basis Währung
     */
    public function _getBaseAmount($amount)
    {
        $currentCurrency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency();
        $baseCurrency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency();

        if ($baseCurrency->getCode() == $currentCurrency->getCode())
        {
            $baseAmount = $amount;
        }
        else
        {
            $baseAmount = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amount, $currentCurrency, $baseCurrency);
        }

        return $baseAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Zuweisen des Versandaufpreises an das Address Objekt zur Anzeige
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Webkochshop_Versandaufpreis_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping_Surcharge
     */
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if ($address->getRalZwischensumme() > 0)
        {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => 'RAL Zwischensumme',
                'value' => $address->getRalZwischensumme()
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Update:

Im not 100% sure yet, but I think I needed to also add the attribute to the quote table, now my custom total "ral_zwischensumme" is ready and can show.
It can show after I added it, but I also did other stuff, so Im not sure if it works because of that stuff or because of the install script. I have to check.

```
<?php
/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup $installer
 */

Mage::Log("wr_epo_sales_setup: ral_zwischensumme zu quote hinzugefügt", 7, "setup.log", true);

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute('quote', 'ral_zwischensumme',
        array(
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'RAL Zwischensumme'
        )
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$quoteData = $quote->getData();    //getData() is not necessary, you could also directly access the getter methods, hint: use var_dump($quoteData) to see all the data.
$addressData = $address->getData();

$tax = $addressData['tax_amount']; //equal to $address->getData('tax_amount') and equal to $address->getTaxAmount();
$shipping = $address->getData('shipping_amount');
$subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
$ralZwischensumme = $quote->getRalZwischensumme();
$grandTotal = $address->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Your answer was leading me to the right direction. Thx! I will edit your answer to include my solution so I can accept it.